# Where does "The Blacklist: Redemption" appear in the canonical viewing order for "The Blacklist"?

Tags: chronology, suggested-order, the-blacklist, the-blacklist-redemption

I'm currently working my way through *The Blacklist* from the beginning.

At which point should I leave the main show and watch episodes of the spin-off series?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding *The Blacklist: Redemption* is a spin off, a backdoor pilot from *The Blacklist* episode 3.22 "Alexander Kirk".

It premired on February 23, 2017 and ended the following April (13th), which means it was shown intermittenly with the second half of *The Blacklist's* Fourth Season, which aired September 22, 2016 and ran to May 18, 2017.

So it seems like somewhere during the fouth season is the right place to watch it. I have not seen it, so I am unsure how much cross-over there is and/or if it's mostly self contained.